# Make code get role then do action Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

How do I make it when sending a message make bot check role then reply to that message, Ive tryed for so long, but can't figure it out. This is tje first time making a bot so trying to get better. This dosen't work, just spams even tho I dont have role

```
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    user = ctx.author
    role = 1008827487024849097
    if role in user.guild.roles:
        if ctx.content == "hi":
            await ctx.reply("hi")
```

Answer (score -1):

Currently you are just looking to see if a number is in `user.guild.roles`, with `ctx.guld.get_role` you are looking for the actual role object.

Also I'd recommend adding a quick guard at the top in the form of:

```
    if ctx.author == bot.user:
        return
```

This protects the script from listening to the bots messages, otherwise your bot will loop infinitely.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author == bot.user:
        return

    user = ctx.author
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(1008827487024849097)
    if role in user.roles:
        if ctx.content == "hi":
            await ctx.reply("hi")
```

In future it is helpful to post the error messages you are getting so people can help you quicker. Hope this helps!

Comment: It dosen't care about my role, its replying even tho I dont have an role

Comment: Well, you're checking `user.guild.roles`, you probably want to actually check `user.roles`

Comment: @SMC I was replying to the OP. Right now it checks if the role is in the guild.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).